# Can I somehow map an entity with hibernate and have conditional logic in a getter for a property?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know it's somewhat possible with @Formula annotation, but I need to implement some java logic in the getter that involves non-persistant objects.
How do I do that?

update:
I use properties like this

```
<property name="computedValue" type="double" not-null="true">
    <meta inherit="false"</meta>
    <column name="computedValue" not-null="false" />
</property>
```

and if i try to create a custom getter via "class-code" attribute, it fails because of similar method signature with the automatically generated method.

This is the closest I got to what I need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be easier if we could see the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails because of similar method signature with the automatically generated method." Who is generating the method?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I mean default get/set method are generated automatically for all properties, and I am looking for a way to customize them. When I simply add my version of a method, it doesn't replace the default method and because of two methods with the same signature in the same class - it fails

Comment: Who is generating them?

Comment: Hibernate does...